# getting all possible combinations of multiple vectors of different size

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a grid search in MATLAB, and I want to compute the parameter combinations beforehand, and I want to search for different grids, like I search parameter 1 in `[10,100,1000]`, but parameter 2 in `[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]`, so I want to compute the combination matrix

```
[10 0
100 0
1000 0
10 0.25
100 0.25
...
1000 1]
```

which has 15 (= 3 x 5 == (`|p1|`x `|p2|`)) rows, each one is a unique combination of these parameters.

the parameters will be supplied in a cell (of unknown size, so it might be more than 2) and the sizes are different.

How can I achieve this with MATLAB?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: I think this is an exact duplicate of the linked answer. Let us know if that's not the case!

Comment: Thanks, @LuisMendo :) I tried to search but couldn't find this one. **Edit** : Yes it is, and it's a really good solution. Thanks for that too, good work :)

Comment: Thank you! Glad it was what you wanted